# Which method is better when I want to search the min and max result in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table called student,I want to get the max and min score,so I write the sql in first way:

```
select max(score),min(score) from student;
```

and the second way:

```
select max(score) from student;
select min(score) from student;
```

I search from the internet and they say that the second way is better because the oracle can not scan the index in the same time.But the second way can not ensure the same datasoure because it do twice searching.How to fix it?

Comment: Get an execution plan. That will tell you if the index can be used properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine the two queries from the second method into a single query:

```
select
    (select max(score) from student),
    (select min(score) from student)
from dual;
```

That solution uses two fast index scans.  It should run faster than option 1 or 2 and will also be consistent.

---

**Why doesn't the simplest solution work?**

It certainly seems like Oracle *should* have a way to run this optimally:

```
select max(score),min(score) from student;
```

I've seen this query before, seen people discuss it, and Oracle even has special access paths for getting the max and min: `INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)`.  But it just can't seem to do both the min and the max at the same time and I'm not sure why.

It's hard to prove Oracle *can't* do something.  Maybe someone will come in later and prove me wrong.  My answer is based on [this article](https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/category/index-full-scan-minmax/) by Richard Foote, who is perhaps the world's top Oracle index expert.  And I've included some simple tests below.  The sample schema looks like an ideal case for Oracle to automatically use the `INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)` twice in one query, but it doesn't.  My results were generated using the latest version, 12.2.

**Sample Schema**

```
--Create STUDENT table with 1.6 million rows, an index on score, and fresh statistics.
--drop table student;
create table student(name varchar2(100), score number not null);
insert into student select lpad('A', 20, 'A'), level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
insert into student select * from student;
insert into student select * from student;
insert into student select * from student;
insert into student select * from student;
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'STUDENT');
end;
/
create index student_idx on student(score);
```

**Option 1: Simplest query with both min and max - doesn't work**

The simplest query uses an `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN`.  Which is probably better than a full table scan, but can still be expensive for large indexes.

```
explain plan for select max(score),min(score) from student;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 4052181173

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |             |     1 |     5 |   972   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |             |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| STUDENT_IDX |  1600K|  7812K|   972   (2)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Option 2 - Only MIN or MAX in one query**

Running one-at-a-time results in an optimal plan with a super-low cost of 3.  It has the `INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)` operation.  This is probably as fast as it gets, although it only returns half the answer.  Using `MIN` instead of `MAX` returns the same plan.

```
--MIN works the same way
explain plan for select max(score) from student;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 3501948619

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |             |     1 |     5 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE            |             |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| STUDENT_IDX |     1 |     5 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Option 3 - Combining MIN and MAX with subqueries**

Combining the two with subqueries takes a bit more code but the result will be much faster than the simpler query in option 1.  The cost looks a little higher than twice the cost of option 2, but when you factor in the extra round-trip to the database, option 3 will be the fastest.

There are other ways to do this in one query, such as using a `UNION ALL`.

```
explain plan for
select
    (select max(score) from student),
    (select min(score) from student)
from dual;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 661746414

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |             |     1 |       |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE            |             |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| STUDENT_IDX |     1 |     5 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |  SORT AGGREGATE            |             |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|   4 |   INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| STUDENT_IDX |     1 |     5 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |  FAST DUAL                 |             |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm sure you did flush the cache (shared pool?) before doing those comparisons - right? If your theory is right, this should have been visible in the last test, where you compare `min` and `max` together, but it's not. The only place where we see real number of rows and bytes is the first test, so ... Also, I'd suggest that having `min` and `max` in the same query is more efficient, because this results in only one round trip to the Database.

Comment: @g00dy Sorry my wording was confusing.  I changed the description for option 3.  Thanks for pointing out the round trip time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ma,mi from
(select max(score) ma from student) a,
(select min(score) mi from student) b
```