# In Oracle 18c, why is max() much less efficient than order by with fetch first 1 rows only?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I have a table with about a billion rows that is partitioned by `date` and has a (local) index on `someNr`. This query:

```
select max("date") from T where someNr = 1;
```

executes within milliseconds, as expected. However, if there is no entry with `someNr = 1`, the query takes **about a minute**. I then found out that:

```
select "date" from T where someNr = 1 order by "date" desc fetch first 1 rows only;
```

executes within milliseconds, regardless of whether there is an entry with `someNr = 1`.

The actual plan in our production DB for `max("date")`:
[image]

The actual plan in our production DB for `order by`:
[image]

After searching for over an hour, I could not find a satisfying explanation. Either they had no proper index, used `rownum < 2` or the answer didn't really answer the question.

The following minimal reproducer **is similar** to the real world scenario and shows the difference in the explain plan:

```
SELECT BANNER FROM v$version;

create table T ("DATE" date not null, SOME_NR int not null);
alter table T
  modify PARTITION BY RANGE ("DATE")
    INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY'))
    (partition "old" values less than (to_date('01-JAN-2023', 'DD-MON-YYYY') ));
create index I_T_DATE ON T ("DATE", SOME_NR);

explain plan for
select max("DATE") from T where SOME_NR = 1;

select plan_table_output
from table (dbms_xplan.display('plan_table', null, 'basic'));

explain plan for
select "DATE" from T where SOME_NR = 1 order by "DATE" fetch first 1 rows only;

select plan_table_output
from table (dbms_xplan.display('plan_table', null, 'basic'));
```

Output:

```
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

+-------------------------------------------------+
|PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|Plan hash value: 1357496781                      |
|                                                 |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|| Id  | Operation                    | Name     ||
|-------------------------------------------------|
||   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |          ||
||   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |          ||
||   2 |   FIRST ROW                  |          ||
||   3 |    PARTITION RANGE ALL       |          ||
||   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| I_T_DATE ||
+-------------------------------------------------+


+-------------------------------------------+
|PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                          |
+-------------------------------------------+
|Plan hash value: 3984456263                |
|                                           |
|-------------------------------------------|
|| Id  | Operation              | Name     ||
|-------------------------------------------|
||   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |          ||
||   1 |  VIEW                  |          ||
||   2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY|          ||
||   3 |    PARTITION RANGE ALL |          ||
||   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN    | I_T_DATE ||
+-------------------------------------------+
```

So why, as it seems, is Oracle's `max()` not smart enough to just sort by date descending and use the first value in the same way that `order by` + `fetch first 1 rows only`? I understand that `max()` may return `null` whereas the second option doesn't, but this really shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: Your question starts by talking about queries with the filter `where someNr = 1` but when you provide the `EXPLAIN PLAN`s the queries do not use a filter and the column you were filtering on does not exist and neither does the index. Which behaviour are you asking about? If it is the behaviour with a `WHERE` filter then your [MRE] should include that filter in the `EXPLAIN PLAN`s.

Comment: Thanks, `where someNr = 1` as well as the partitioning has no relevant effect on the plan, so I skipped those in favor of keeping it *minimal*. I now updated it to include both, but it's actually irrelevant.

Comment: Are you sure those plans are exactly what was happening against your  billion row table? You can't expect the same plan with an empty test table and a billion row table. When I run your minimal test case it shows me INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX) which is what you want. But when I load the table with a few hundred thousand bogus records and then gather stats, it changes to INDEX FAST FULL SCAN which is quite different. You have to ensure you are representing the actual plan being used by the 1-minute-long execution you are trying to tune. You can look at the sql plan hash value or sql child number.

Comment: The screenshots I included are from our production database so yes, I am sure that's precisely what's happening :) I know the test table won't produce the same, that's why I explicitly said it's *similar* and that's why I included both, the test table plan and the production plan. They're not identical but the essence is the same;  `max()` does a `INDEX (FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)` which is *not* what I want because, as described, it's way too slow when there is no matching entry.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do; if I don't include a minimal reproducer, people complain that it's missing and when I include one, people complain it's not the same as in production. How would I reproduce the billion rows situation when there are so many variables - which I feel are irrelevant because the example already demonstrates the different plans even though the operation is basically the same :)

Comment: Just because you pulled the plan from production doesn't mean it's the correct plan. Session parameters, bind peeking, literals vs. binds, it can all result in you seeing a different plan when you do an explain plan than the bad-running code. You have to interrogate v$session (or v$active_session_history for the recent past) to get the child cursor number and/or plan hash value and ensure you are looking at the correct cursor in v$sql_plan (or dba_hist_sql_plan for older executions, or with dbms_xplan.display_cursor, or dbms_xplan.display_awr).

Comment: Next, you need to determine where in the plan most of your time was. ASH (v$active_session_history) will give you that information (one row per second, so count the rows and group by the sql_plan_line_id to get seconds per plan line). Once you identify that, based on the plan and the wait event ASH reports (event), you can discern what is happening. By the way, INDEX (FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)) *is* what you want. That MIN/MAX means it knows it can simply jump to the start or end of the index to get your value... it won't actually scan through all the leaf blocks like a normal INDEX FULL SCAN would.

Comment: One other comment, "similar" isn't good enough when it comes to tuning. Any change to the SQL, no matter how small, and any variation in the plan, can have radically diifferent performance results. It is imperative to represent the exact SQL (not a mocked-up fake SQL) and the exact plan that is having problems, or folks can only make educated guesses (at best).

Comment: @PaulW when I execute the `max()` query against our database and it takes 60s and I take a screenshot from the explain plan of that exact execution, how does that not mean it's the correct plan? And if that plan, which uses `INDEX (FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX))` takes 60s, but the other one doesn't how is `INDEX (FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX))` what I want? Posting the *exact* SQL is certainly not how it works on SO, hence people ask for minimal reproducers - which I provided and, by their very nature, are usually *similar*. And again, I *did* post the exact explain plan.

Comment: I already explained how you cannot assume the plan you generate with an "explain plan for" statement is the same that is actually used run-time by Oracle during a real execution. It often is, it very well might be, but it's not guaranteed. You can only know for sure by interrogating the actual plan hash value of the specific child cursor then under execution, which requires using a separate session during execution or querying ASH data after the fact. Oracle even has adaptive plans that change in-flight during execution. It's not as simple as most folks think.

Comment: I suggest the focus not be exclusively on the plan itself. Every plan is potentially the correct plan given the SQL - there's no such thing as a "bad" plan considered in itself. Plans become bad only when they assume things about your *data* that is not correct, and we can't see your data, so we can't know that a plan you share is "bad". You really must use wait-based analysis to determine the issue, and that is going to require querying ASH (v$active_session_history) to find out on exactly what plan line it is spending its time and on what event. That's how to solve perf problems.

Comment: You're assuming I used `explain plan for` but I never said that I did :) I'm using SQL Developer's "Realtime SQL Monitoring" which gives me the exact plan statistics and plan. Actually, you can even see it in the screenshot that what I'm showing is the plan statistics. But I really don't get why we're discussing such details when fact is: max() can be slower than order/limit and the questions is: How can it be? It's really a theoretical question and I'm not the first person facing this issue. I can try to extend the reproducer so that you can see it with your own eyes if you don't believe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that Oracle's MIN/MAX index algorithm is not very smart. It appears to only be capable of traversing an index one time to get either the largest or the smallest value. And Oracle does not often transform queries to use MIN/MAX, so you'll need to rewrite your query to take advantage of that algorithm.

I can't truly answer *why* the algorithm isn't smart. I would guess it's a vicious circle, where Oracle didn't invest much effort into making MIN/MAX smart initially, so it's not used often, therefore it's not worth investing more effort to improve. The MIN/MAX option is not even listed in the otherwise-comprehensive [PLAN_TABLE reference in the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/optimizer-ref.html#GUID-7957B335-D36A-42BF-96BB-FF47FFBA4DFD)

As an example of how dumb MIN/MAX can be, a query can only use either MIN or MAX, not both. A query like `SELECT MIN(A),MAX(B) FROM SOME_TABLE` needs to be re-written as `SELECT (SELECT MIN(A) FROM SOME_TABLE), (SELECT MAX(B) FROM SOME_TALBE) FROM DUAL` to take advantage of MIN/MAX. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132367/409172) for more details about this limitation.

But understanding the algorithm's limitations can help us craft a query that might work better. We can use MIN/MAX once to quickly get the maximum value, and then plug that value back into the query. The below plan generates one "INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)" and one "INDEX RANGE SCAN", but reading the index twice with those operations is likely faster than your query which performs a regular "INDEX FULL SCAN".

```
explain plan for
select "DATE"
from T
where SOME_NR = 1
  --This subquery improves performance by enabling the (MIN/MAX) option.
  and "DATE" = (select max("DATE") from T where SOME_NR = 1)
order by "DATE" fetch first 1 rows only;

select plan_table_output
from table (dbms_xplan.display('plan_table', null, 'basic'));


Plan hash value: 206361108
 
---------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name     |
---------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |          |
|   1 |  VIEW                          |          |
|   2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY        |          |
|   3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN            | I_T_DATE |
|   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE             |          |
|   5 |      FIRST ROW                 |          |
|   6 |       INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| I_T_DATE |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Seems like the answer is "nobody can tell" :) Thank you!